# Slightly difficult cipher

Tags: cipher

This cipher is in English.

60 30
42 90 90
30 51 81 60 71 61
50 42 91 20
61 20 20 10 61
42 51 20
42 90 90
61 20 20 10 61
30 51 81 60 71 61

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**)  I'm glad you're eager to contribute a puzzle here, but I fear this one is not going to fare well. You may want to read [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717) for some guidance on how to turn a cipher challenge into an interesting puzzle. You may benefit from looking around the site, and in particular checking out the high voted puzzles in the tags that appeal to you, to get a better sense of what kinds of puzzles work best here. Welcome again, and hope your next puzzle sees great success!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be

> a substitution cipher, which translates as:
>  **If all fruits have seeds are all seeds fruits**
>
>  20 is common and appears in doubles; 90 also appears in doubles.
>  20=E and 90=L, followed by 61=S, 71=T, 51=R, are reasonable guesses.
>  The rest follow from there.
>  Spaces are not represented in the cipher.

If there's a rhyme or reason to the number values, I'm drawing a blank.

> They tend to run in sequences by 10s, but the starts and stops are ... strange:
>    42=A
>    10=D 20=E 30=F 40=g 50=H 60=I 70=j 80=k 90=L
>    11=n 21=o 31=p 41=q 51=R 61=S 71=T 81=U 91=V
>  (lower-case entries are speculative).
>
>  What values would be assigned to B, C, D, W, X, Y, Z in this scheme is a mystery to me.

Comment: The rhyme and reason is that you swap the tens and ones, take the number as zero-based index into the alphabet and then caesar-shift by 2.

Comment: @MOehm Oh, sure, go and make sense of it why don't you. :)

Comment: Correct, I award you one million Good Boy Points.

Answer (score 1):

Rubio's answer above is, as far as I can tell, correct. Here's a bit of an explanation on how to get there (without resorting to torturing letter frequencies):

> Start by swapping the two digits on each number. This puts all numbers in the 1-26 range:
>
> ```
> 6 3 24 9 9 3 15 18 6 17 16 5 24 19 2 16 2 2 1 16 24 15 2 24 9 9 16 2 2 1 16 3 15 18 6 17 16
> ```
>
> Convert these to the corresponding letter:
>
> ```
> F C X I I C O R F Q P E X S B P B B A P X O B X I I P B B A P C O R F Q P
> ```
>
> When Caesar-Shifted by 2 they become
>
> ```
> IFALLFRUITSHAVESEEDSAREALLSEEDSFRUITS
> ```